# Making the installer ask before adding value to RUN-key in the registry (InstallShield)

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, installation, registry, installshield

I am creating an installer with **InstallShield Limited Edition** in VS2012, and want the user to have the choice of having the application start when Windows does.

The installer currently creates the registry value upon install;

[image: The registry value to be added by the installer]
That's very nice and dandy and it works.

**BUT** I feel it's bad practice and not particularly kind on the users to force a startup application upon them.

The user can currently choose to set the setting in the options panel of the (WPF) application, which behind the scenes will register a value in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, so the app will start with Windows. However, I would like the user to have the choice of turning this on already at install-time.

In essence, I want a checkbox sometime during the install user can set, and if the checkbox is set to 'yes', the installer will create the registry key (and if not, well, you know...)

How should I go about creating a dialog with a check-box, that would affect whether the registry key was created or not?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you have a tools | options type screen in your app and ask the user there if they would like to have it autorun.   That way it's not an installer problem.